# How can I use a crate within a git submodule that lives within its own workspace?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to consume an external project however they don't have a crate (they distribute an executable and I am trying to pull functionality out of their project).

Their project is within a workspace, is it possible to consume packages from a nested workspace?

```
/third-party (git-submodule)
  /crates
    /some_lib
  Cargo.toml (workspace)
/my-project
  Cargo.toml
Cargo.toml (workspace)
```

I tried

```
cd third-party && cargo build && cd ..
cargo build
```

where my local package specifies this in the `Cargo.toml`

```
some_lib = { path = "../third-party/crates/some_lib" }
```

However cargo complains that

```
Caused by:
  failed to load manifest for dependency `deno_runtime`

Caused by:
  failed to parse manifest at `/home/username/development/project/deno/runtime/Cargo.toml`

Caused by:
  error inheriting `edition` from workspace root manifest's `workspace.package.edition`

Caused by:
  `workspace.package.edition` was not defined
```

Is the only realistic options to fork the project and publish a crate that exports the functionality I need?

Comment: Just as an aside, if you fork it, you can use it as a git dependency, you don't have to publish it

Comment: Your error message and your directory tree do not match.